# Sound playing through SKAction but not through AVAudioPlayer

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I've got a vexing problem with getting sound to play in a game but can't seem to get any output through the AVAudioPlayer. Originally this was set up as a class but when it didn't work I tried hardcoding a sound output just to check if there was a problem there. It still didn't work and I tried a few different files to rule out a problematic audio file or format.The URL is being retrieved but the audioPlayer simply seems to be outputting no sound.

I've read a few threads about similar issues and fiddled with system sound settings but it's made no difference. It's been suggested that the Simulator can't output sound in some circumstances but I don't believe this is the case here.

```
let myFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("gong", ofType: "wav")!)
    print ("URL data: \(myFile)")
    do{
        let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:myFile)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()    
    }catch {
        print("Error playing sound")
    }
```

However this plays fine:

```
  self.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("gong", waitForCompletion: false))
```

I need the functionality of AVAudioPlayer as I want to be able to start stop and control the volume of the sound as it loops. I'm using XCode 7.3.1 and Swift 2.2.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Kw

Comment: You imported AVFoundation right?

Comment: Yes. I think I worked it out. I needed to create an instance on the AVAudioPlayer in a scope that is persistent so it is not removed by the auto garbage collection. Also, I think the prepareToPlay command does not have time to load the file into memory before the play command is executed AND the player also goes out of scope and is collected almost instantly when the code block it is called in is exited. Result: not a chance of it playing. I'm going to create a class that preloads all the sounds into memory at the init() stage with prepareToPlay so they can be called to play instantly. Thanks

Comment: That was something I was going to say, I've never used the `prepareToPlay` method, and I've been told it's usually not necessary.

Comment: It is necessary - you get quite a long delay (0.5 - 1 sec) while it loads into memory which stops all other processes. Its very jarring in a game.

Comment: The reason that happens is because `AVAudioPlayer`'s `play()` method is actually asynchronous - so you should be calling it asynchronously. A lot of people don't realize this. Please see an answer I posted that explains.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking about **Swift 2**, I think you should try a different approach to get the url:

```
import AVFoundation

func playMusic(filename: String) {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
    if (url == nil) {
        print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
        return
    }
    do { backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!, fileTypeHint: nil) }
    catch let error as NSError { print(error.description) }
    if let player = backgroundMusicPlayer {
        player.volume = 1
        player.numberOfLoops = -1
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add an answer that helps me. `AVAudioPlayer`'s `play()` method is asynchronous, so I've actually found the best way to play a sound file without experiencing lag the first time it's loaded into memory is by calling it asynchronously:

**SWIFT 2**

```
import AVFoundation

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

init() {

    let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FileName", ofType: "wav")!)
    if let soundURL = soundURL {

        do {
            self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }
    } else {
        // Handle situation where URL isn't found
        print("Sound file URL not found")
    }

}

func playSound() {
    guard let audioPlayer = audioPlayer else { return }
    // Now we can play the sound asynchronously - which will eliminate any lag upon initial play
    let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
        audioPlayer.play()
    })

}
```

**SWIFT 3**

```
import AVFoundation

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

init() {

    let soundURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FileName", ofType: "wav")!)
    if let soundURL = soundURL {

        do {
            self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.description)
        }
    } else {
        // Handle situation where URL isn't found
        print("Sound file URL not found")
    }

}

func playSound() {
    guard let audioPlayer = audioPlayer else { return }
    // Now we can play the sound asynchronously - which will eliminate any lag upon initial play
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

}
```

The idea of this is to incorporate some sort of SoundManager class into your model. I usually create a class like this that has an `AVAudioPlayer` for every sound I need throughout my app, and I can instantiate it when I load my ViewController - which will initialize the individual audioPlayers upon it's own `init()` method. Then I can play each file by using my own play methods. If you have a bunch of different sounds, it can also help to use an `enum` to organize different files, and have one custom `play()` method that will play whichever file is passed in as a request.

Comment: Thanks Pierce. I did end up doing something very similar to this. I created a dictionary of AVAudioPlayer objects with the filename of the sound file as a key. A method targets the player via the filename passed as a parameter and they play instantly. The only problem is that you have a single AVAudioPlayer for each sound so you can't have multiple instances of the same sound playing simultaneously. I improved that situation by setting the sound to reset to its start when a second play call arrives while its still playing. It sounds perfect in most situations. Hope this is useful & thanks all.